# Why do I get an error "...depends on uninitialised value" in valgrind  output?

Tags: c, valgrind

How can I suppress this error in valgrind's output?

```
==16727== 1 errors in context 2 of 18:
==16727== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
```

What causes this error? Can I just ignore it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that one of your control path is such that an variable/data does not get initialized when that control path gets executed. Unitialized variables usually result in Undefined Behavior So valgrind detects it and reports it.

Have a look at **[this](https://computing.llnl.gov/code/memcheck/#deciphering4)**, It shall help you understand the error.

Also, add the flag `--track-origins=yes` to valgrind and it will give you information on the sources of uninitialised data.

Comment: ...and you shouldn't ignore them. IMO you shouldn't ignore anything in the valgrind output without at least investigating them first. When you know why the report appear you can choose to ignore it or not. Specifically "possibly lost" is often easy to decide to ignore, once investigated.